# prevent min-content columns from expanding

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS-grid with the following columns:

```
.grid {
   width: 500px;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto;
}

.item-span {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  // Same result width
  // grid-columns: span 3;
}
```

And in my grid:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div class="item-span">
       Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem: the width of 1 / 2 / 3 become bigger even though they should not. Since item-span spans on 3 items, it should allow content up to 500px and then break (or overflow). The same effect can be achieved with fixed widths (see jsfiddle).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Do I need to remove long words from my grid?

https://jsfiddle.net/156y0ajv/

edit: after some testing I found out that applying the following would solve the problem. But it still looks like a bug to me.

```
.item-span {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    // Same result width
    // grid-columns: span 3;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 0;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto;
}

.item {

}

.item-span {
  color: #3a843a;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.text {
    padding: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 4</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 5</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 6</span></div>
  <div class="item-span">A short text does not break layout.</div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item-span">But when a german word is too long, the first and second column are bigger than their min-content.</div>
  <div class="item-span" style="color:#bf1717;">Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz</div>
  
  <div class="item-span">Try adding display:none to the upper span.</div>
  <div class="item-span" style="color:#bf1717;"><div style="width: 250px">Similarly: fixed width cause the same issue</div></div>
  <div class="item-span"><div style="width: 20%">But for some reason: % width works perfectly.</div></div>
  <div class="item-span"><div style="width: 150%">Even 150% works without breaking the widths!</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `auto`

The `auto` value takes the **length of the container** and distributes that space evenly across `auto` tracks. In this example, three columns have equal widths. Together they consume the full width of the container.

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.item-span {
  /* display: none; */  /*  toggle this */
  background-color: white;
  color: #3a843a;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.text {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 4</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 5</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 6</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item-span" style="color:#bf1717;">Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz</div>
</div>
```

---

### `min-content`

The `min-content` value takes the **length of the content** and distributes that space evenly across `min-content` tracks. In this example, three columns have equal widths. Together they consume the full width of the content.

```
grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.item-span {
  /* display: none; */ /*  toggle this */
  background-color: white;
  color: #3a843a;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.text {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 4</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 5</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 6</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item-span" style="color:#bf1717;">Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz</div>
</div>
```

---

### `auto` and `min-content`

When you mix these values together (like in your code), you get a seemingly arbitrary combination of lengths. However, there is nothing arbitrary about them. The calculations are based on grid algorithms. (See sections [7.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing), [11.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-track-sizing) and [11.8](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-stretch) in the grid spec.)

```
grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.item-span {
  /* display: none; */ /*  toggle this */
  background-color: white;
  color: #3a843a;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.text {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 4</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 5</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 6</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item-span" style="color:#bf1717;">Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz</div>
</div>
```

---

### `1fr` solution

If your goal is `min-content` for columns 1 & 2, you don't need `auto` on column 3. Actually, you don't even need `min-content` at all.

Set column 3 to `1fr`, that will then consume all free space on the line, squeezing all extra space out of columns 1 & 2.

This will do:

```
grid-template-columns: min-content min-content 1fr;
```

and so will this:

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.item-span {
  /* display: none; */ /*  toggle this */
  background-color: white;
  color: #3a843a;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.text {
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 4</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 5</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 6</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 1</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 2</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span class="text">item 3</span></div>
  <div class="item-span" style="color:#bf1717;">Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/156y0ajv/1/)